# finding the error in a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

can anyone help me out with this sentence on error correction ? :

> many goods are being manufactured quickly without/ any regard for quality and as consumers we must be / aware of our rights and the government / should penalize them who indulge in unscrupulous business practices

along with this I have one more doubt, how could you use "THEM WHO" in a sentence, is that even grammatically correct ?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. There are many issues with the quote: capitalisation, punctuation, style, etc. This archived blog post might be of some help: [Proofreading Questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10573/142322).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, just `who` instead of `them who` seems to make more sense.

> `M`any goods are being manufactured quickly without any regard`s` for quality`. A`s consumers`,` we must be aware of our rights andgovernment should penalize `who` indulge in `such` unscrupulous business practices.

Comment: "who" by itself is not typically used like this. I would expect "those who". Related questions: [“Can I help who's next?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6923), [Can we use “who” by itself as a subject in spoken language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361310)